# Sever side Countdown Timer in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, webforms, countdowntimer

I am having a countdown timer in my web forms using timer and update panel.But after i publish the site the countdown timer lags means stop at 30sec and resume on 25sec the timer is working perfectly but the time between 25-30 sec are skipped.

Here is my code

in .aspx file

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTimerAuction" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="squareBOX">
                       <asp:Timer ID="tm1000ms" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="tm1000ms_Tick"></asp:Timer>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm1000ms" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in .aspx.cs file

in page_load

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
            if (Application["AuctionTimer"] == null) 
            {
                Application.Lock();
                Application["AuctionTimer"] = new CountDownTimer(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30"));
                Application.UnLock();
                (Application["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).Start();
            }

        }
    }
```

In timer tick method

```
  protected void tm1000ms_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     if (Application["AuctionTimer"] != null)
        {
            if (!(Application["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).TimeLeft.ToString().Equals("00:00:00"))
            {
                string rawTime = "";
                string AuctionTime = "";

                rawTime = (Application["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).TimeLeft.ToString();

                AuctionTime = rawTime.Substring(rawTime.IndexOf(":") + 1);

                int timerSec = Convert.ToInt32(AuctionTime.Substring(AuctionTime.IndexOf(":") + 1));

                lblTimer.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                lblTimer.Text = AuctionTime + "sec";
            }
            else
            {
                 if (Session["AdminID"] != null)
                {
                   //Database related classes are called to sold the item
                   // as it is an Auction Website (Live Auction)
                }

                startNewPlayerLoading();
            }
        }
}
```

the startNewPlayerLoading method

```
  private void startNewPlayerLoading()
{
    tm1000ms.Enabled = false; // disabling the timer of countdown
    divitemCard.Visible = false; // disabling the item picture div
    divnewitemCard.Visible = true; // enabling  the New Item Loading DIV
    upPlayerCard.Update(); // Updating update panel as they both are in same Update Panel
    timerblock.Visible = false;  // disabling old countdown timer
    freshTimerBlock.Visible = true;  // enabling new Loading countdown timer
    upFreshAuction.Update(); // Updating update panel as they both are in same Update Panel
    tmPlayerCard.Enabled = true; // enabling  the new Loading timer of countdown
    RestartFreshStopwatch(); // starting the Loading countdown Timer
}
```

and countdown timer class

```
  public class CountDownTimer
{
    public TimeSpan TimeLeft;
    System.Threading.Thread thread;

    public CountDownTimer() { }

    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan original)
    {
        this.TimeLeft = original;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!TimeLeft.Equals(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00")))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Subtract(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01"));
                }
            }
        });
        this.thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"));
        if (this.thread != null)
            this.thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Its works also when page is refresh the timer doesn't start from the beginning but lags sometime .
Anyone have a better idea of how to execute a server side timer and also doesn't restart when refresh..

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking new solution for fixes in same code?

Comment: if some fixes can do the work then well and good but if can't then new solution @Always_a_learner

Comment: why are you implementing timer on web form..have you though if application pool recycle what happended?

Comment: You should use SignalR along with MVC. Have a look to [SignalR-MVC server side timer](https://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-Server-Side-Timers-and-SignalR-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications) article.

Comment: well i am new to asp.net website and i found this solution in web but it lags and i don't know what happens when application pool recycle.

Comment: check my answer